# Counting Number of Pages in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a very big HTML screen which when you print, prints over 16 pages so in Print Preview you can see page breaks. I am trying to display the page number like this: Page X of Y

So display the page number out of the total number of pages and I am trying to display this in a footer that I created see below

```
<div id="footer">
            <p>Page X of Y</p>
</div>
```

But is there a way in either CSS or JavaScript which I can use to achieve this? E.g. a way to count page breaks?

I already tried

```
@page {
 @bottom-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page);
  }

}
```

But this does not work because it has browser compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

When someone wants to print the document, he can chose to display Page X of Y in the print setup menus. I do not recommend adding it yourself with css or js, it will overlap the print script that already do that in a proper way.